# jprofiler giving unknown class name during heap profiling

Tags: java, jprofiler, memory-leak-detector

I am memory profiling a java application with jprofiler ,but I found instance of some unknown class(please check image link below).
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jscq2x2c07x2j16/memory.png

I have class named as xyz.ServiceAppointmentPopup.
but profiler is showing many instance of xyz.ServiceAppointmentPopup$1,xyz.ServiceAppointmentPopup$3,
xyz.ServiceAppointmentPopup$3 etc.
I couldn't find on internet what these extra instances are all about.

Does anyone know about these extra instances.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**$** means it's an inner class inside ServiceAppointmentPopup, the number means it's an anonymous inner class. In general it's a convention to name inner classes like this in the JVM ClassName$InnerClassName.

Comment: Thank you very much sir .it was indeed helpful